# Multiplying two negative numbers inside a square root

Tags: complex-numbers

What is $\sqrt{-2\cdot(-3)}$ ? Whether it is $-\sqrt 6$ or $\sqrt 6$?

Comment: I reckon that $\sqrt 6$ is $\sqrt6$.

Comment: Since you tagged this [tag:complex-numbers] the answer is **Both** :-) Complex numbers simply don't have unique square roots. If you intended the question to be about real numbers then the square roots are always non-negative by convention.

Comment: Also, 1) search the site, we have several questions about misunderstandings related to roots of complex numbers, their multi-valuedness in particular. 2) Please study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). You see, the founder of this place says that this place [is a Wiki first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/). Does it look like this question adds something to a Wiki?